# C# split after "{" and before comma

Tags: c#, regex, split

How to split after first bracket and before comma. 
Forexample

```
string: {England, 120, USA, 30, 40}{Spain, 23, India, 45, 23}{Brazil, 340, Argentine, 39}
```

I want to receive, England, Spain and Argentine from a split function.

Any ideas how to write the regex method or alternative methods?

Comment: And this won't require regex either.

Comment: line.Split('{', ',')

Comment: `(?<=\{)[^,]*` try matching instead of splitting.

Comment: And why in the last section Argentine and not Brazil ?

Answer (score 1):

Its probably easier using Match

```
foreach(Match oMatch in Regex.Matches(string,@"\{([^,]*)"))
    Console.Write(oMatch.Groups[1].Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<={)([^,]*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.Better than splitting.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/60

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression split would split that up fairly easy:

```
{\s*(?<country>[^,]+)[^}]*}
```